# How do I open a second Fancybox inside a first one?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to load ajax content in an overlay window. Like this:

```
<a class="fancybox.ajax" href="first url">Link 1</a>
```

This will open the content:

```
<div>
  <a class="fancybox.ajax" href="second url">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

When I click the Link2 inside the first Fancybox the second Fancybox opens while the first one closes.

How can I open Link 2 such that the first Fancybox stays open and the second Fancybox opens inside the first one?

Comment: only with iframe is possible, not with ajax

Comment: How does it work with iframe?